# How To Grouping Data In WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my WPF Application i'm having datagrid in this datagrid i want to grouping up data from database based on column name called "City" ,i'm not using mvvm architecture and list method,I'm Using ICollectionView and passed datatable object as a parameter,This is my c# code

```
ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt);
                cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(newPropertyGroupDescription("City"));
                Hotels.ItemsSource = cv;
```

And This is my XAML Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" Name="grouping" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Background="Azure" ItemsSource="{Binding Hotels}" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="Hotels" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" Margin="0,173,0,0">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>                        
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

It does not display text in textblock i'm binding Textblock with column name but it does't works...Please help me
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't use viewmodel for each item, but DataTable's row object, WPF can't recognize the name "City". You need to use group's name which is held by `CollectionViewGroupInternal.Name` property of object representing a group item. In this particular scenario it's the name of the city. Just bind `Name` to your TextBlock.

You can achieve your goal in less lines of code using group's HeaderTemplate. Default ItemPresenter will be visible below the Header.

```
<!-- resources -->
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="devicesCollection" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" Source="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- Sorting -->
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

    <!-- Grouping -->
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="City"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
    <Border Background="Gray">
        <TextBlock Margin="10 5 5 5" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- data grid -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=devicesCollection}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GroupingHeader}" />
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I't does't Show anything same result :(

Comment: It can be the problem with CollectionViewSource object. See updated answer.

Comment: Please paste the view model. Could be a typo or something.

Comment: 'ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt. AsDataView()) ;' this?

Comment: I missed that information, sorry. Bind `Name` to your TextBlock. Answer updated.

Comment: <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" /> i got error in this line then i add namespace xmlns:compModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"  still i got error comp:SortDescription was not found verify that you are not missing assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built